# nesting div within span problem

Tags: html

div is a block element and span is an inline element so according to xhtml 1.0 validation it is not right but still several websites uses this method for styling is it all right ? or it will cause some problem please help me ?

Comment: Which method are you talking about? Your question is not clear... could you please post some sample code?

Comment: <span><div></div></span> this type of statement is not valid but still many website used to do this why

Comment: probably because the authors of said HTML don't understand where container tags like <span> and <div> are supposed to be used. You would be surprised at how many folks have *not* heard of the terms 'block element' and 'inline element'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not right + You never need to do this => thus **never should**.

Comment: but still some website uses this approach for example i saw the code of google in firebug they also used div nested in span

Comment: So what? You still **never** need to do it and it is **always** wrong. Other authors might be willing to write bad code and risk more bugs and more undefined behaviour in exchange for … well, nothing … but that is no reason to do it.

Comment: Google is famous for using 'non-validating' code. They optimize for size and speed, not valid markup.

Comment: What will happen if you do put a div inside a span? I mean in the real world, not in "it must validate" world?

Comment: adinas: the browser will try to interpet it in their own (unspecified/unpredictable) way. It might work out fine, it might break. It might work now, break later. You should not rely (too) much on unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @Konerak yes it would work, but having to make invalid HTML function right makes it harder for new people come along and create a new browser. The principle of specifications is that it makes interoperability possible. Given how hard it is to create a browser, it may be pointless, but adhering to specifications is important. Not just for browsers but maybe for scraping or linters.

Answer (score 4):

Websites that do that wont be 'strict xhtml compliant' but in reality HTML like this will work just fine in any modern browser. That doesn't mean you should do it though - because theres no need to.

Answer (score 4):

As of today 11th March 2014, modern browsers WILL give you problem as they render block element differently from inline element.

I encountered this incident myself, read my experience and solution: http://diophung.blogspot.sg/2014/03/web-developer-conform-to-w3c-standards.html

It's wrong, and embarrassing for not knowing such standard (your web designers will laugh at you) !

Answer (score 4):

Nesting div within span may cause **serious problem** in firefox when you need to get the offsetTop(offsetLeft) of the span.

However this performs normal in chrome(v57.0.2987.98).

so I agree with the answer of Konerak:

> "the browser will try to interpet it in their own
>   (unspecified/unpredictable) way. It might work out fine, it might
>   break. It might work now, break later. "

It all depends on the browser itself.
The specification about the offsetTop/offsetLeft is here:
https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop

The following is my testing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin:100px">
        <span id="span-divWrapper">
            <div id="div-nestedInSpan" style="border:1px solid black;">I am the div nested in span</div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <button onclick="showDivOffsetTop()">show div offsetTop</button>
    <button onclick="showSpanOffsetTop()">show span offsetTop</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById("div-nestedInSpan");
        var span = document.getElementById("span-divWrapper");
        var showDivOffsetTop = function(){
            alert(div.offsetTop);
        }
        var showSpanOffsetTop = function(){
            alert(span.offsetTop);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```