# Can i used div tag in span tag in HTML5

Tags: html

```
<a id="speakerPressingAnch" name="speakerPressingAnch">
                    <span id="speakerPressingButton" class="icon-speakerPressing"></span>

<!--  I have used div tag here -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

I have used div tag here as following:

```
<span id="speakerPressingtext">Push <br>  To  <br> &nbsp;Talk </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<!--                <img id="speakerPressingButton" src="" />-->

                </a>
```

Comment: yes you can..what issue you are facing I can't understand from your query?

Comment: Yes you can. Its not valid though. 

Reference [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919909/nesting-div-within-span-problem

Comment: The edit function is there for you to *clarify* your question, not vandalize it. Please don't do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not valid and you never need to do this.

You can't put `div` element into `span` element. because `div` is `block` type element and `span` is `inline` type element.

I think no need to put `div` element into `span` element.