# How to scroll to nth-child using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello using `Jquery` how can i scroll an element (with `overflow`) to children element ?

```
<span id="gran">
 <span id="parent">
  <div class="a">
   Casa
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa
  </div>
 </span>
</span>

#gran {
overflow: auto;
}
```

I want to scroll **#gran** to third element with class `a` so i tried this but doesn't work:

```
 $("#gran").scrollTo('#parent > div:nth-child(3)');
```

I hope in your help :)
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: [nesting-div-within-span-problem??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919909/nesting-div-within-span-problem) .. also `span:nth-child(3)` Is it a span or div?? in html its a div in jquery code its a span??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef sorry i edit jquery....but doens't work yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it can be done

- You need to set `max-height` with `overflow : auto` to let the element scrollable without that it will keep extending without scrollbar .. if you need to use the document/body scrollbar use `$('body , html')` [Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)
- You need to use `animate()` function with `scrollTop` and `offset()/position()`

```js
//$("#gran").scrollTo('#parent > div:nth-child(3)');

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gran').animate({
      scrollTop: - $('#gran').offset().top + $("#parent > div:nth-child(3)").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#to_remove{
  background : red;
  height : 100px;

}

#gran {
overflow: auto;
max-height : 500px;
}
.a{
  height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to_remove"></div>

<div id="gran">
 <div id="parent">
  <div class="a">
   Casa 1
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa 2
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa 3
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa 4
  </div>
  <div class="a">
   Casa 5
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works well but i don't understand why in my case (where html is a little bit more diffucult with 3 div inside a parent overflow) nth-child works only for "even"

Comment: @Borja If you've only 3 divs in a prarent and your code try to scroll to the third/last one it will scroll fine but up to the 3rd div height .. if its height smaller then the `#gran` height it will not scroll to the top of the `#gran` for sure .. because its no more height/content for  scrollbar to scroll

Comment: Nooo is really strange problem... for odd nth-child i have error "can't access property "top"" but if is even nth-child (2-4-6 ecc) works well. Whattttt !?!? :D

Comment: @Borja If you've a live website let me check it for you

Comment: no is a file...maybe the problem is about some properties of each div (child). Maybe it can has display: inline ?

Comment: @Borja I don't think its about `display` ok see updated answer and see .. i added `$(document).ready(` and `setTimeout` to let the website take more few seconds to run the scroll action .. lets try an see

Comment: if #parent has 8 div but nth-child works only for even...

Comment: @Borja Yes its strange .. I can't tell what is wrong specially while I can't see the code live.. keep trying and if you find a solution please let me know

Comment: Yes you are right...and i thank your for the help :)